# send mail or SMS in J2ME

Tags: java-me

This is my first time to send mail or SMS in J2ME, I have search and I found that I have to make a form that take the information of email or the SMS and use some APIs like Wireless Messaging (WMA JSR 120) to send it.

I'm asking if there is another option that can open an ready application of the phone that send email or SMS in popup or something like that and keep my application running and when send it it will close this application or that is not found in J2ME?

Answer (score 3):

If your target handset is a Nokia you may use MIDlet platformRequest as described in http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/developers-guides/invoking-applications/invoking-applications-in-java-me.html

Example:

Opening SMS editor for sending SMS to a specified telephone number: platformRequest("sms:+19123456789");

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [JSR-211: Content Handler API](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=211). Unfortunately, I don't think even that will solve your problem.

The basic purpose of JSR211 is to allow Inter Process Communication between applications in J2ME.

There is however a huge difference between the amount of effort required to implement an IPC system between MIDlets on a phone and the amount of effort required to re-design most of the applications on the phone in order to make them all do something useful using this IPC mechanism, especially when a phone supports several development runtimes.

As far as I know, there is no existing J2Me phone that contains a messaging application that supports sending SMS or e-mail from a MIDLet via JSR211.

To be fair, I think I have only ever used JSR211 between MIDlets or to install DRM licenses before.